# Importing XML data into a XFA PDF form [using Python]

Tags: python, xml, pdf, pdf-generation, xfa

**What I currently have:** A XFA PDF form, and a .dat file (all txt format inside)

**What I need to do:** Import the .dat data into the XFA PDF form

**Current thought process:**

- Convert .dat data into XML format
- Extract fields from XFA PDF file
- Import converted XML data into the XFA PDF file using the extracted
  fields

**Problems**:

- Field extraction; pdftk cannot be used, since the PDF form is XFA not AcroForm; Is there any way to do this without subscribing to Acrobat/Livecycle? Also, pdfminer is not giving good results here, it seems to not work with the XFA format.
- XML import into PDF; No good idea on how to actually do this, do any python modules exist?

Comment: Hi! Did you ever find a solution? I need to do the same thing...